# Stop javafx Timeline when table size becomes zero

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview, timeline

```
Timeline addRandomPeopleFrequently = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(table.getItems().size()==0)
                {

                    try {
                        stop();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                int index = RNG.nextInt(table.getItems().size());
                count++;
                table.getItems().remove(index);
                e=System.currentTimeMillis() -s;
            }  
          }));  

          addRandomPeopleFrequently.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);  
          addRandomPeopleFrequently.play();
```

I have this code and I want to stop **Timeline** when size of my table becomes 0.
This code is **not** working any sugegstion what to do

Answer (score 0):

You are stopping

```
javafx.​application.​Application.stop();
```

which does nothing, instead do

```
addRandomPeopleFrequently.stop();
```

Comment: If you tried that, you'd get compiler error `addRandomPeopleFrequently might not have been initialized`

Comment: @ajeh I didn't give details, but that eventhandler should be defined and initiated separately, after the initialization of addRandomPeopleFrequently.

Comment: Similar timelines only worked for me if `addRandomPeopleFrequently` was a class field created in a constructor, as anonymous class instance can only use final local variables.